# Why am I getting an error message that says "Invalid Object Name" when I've declared my variable in the current batch?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
declare @docs table(
    DocID int
)

insert into @docs (DocID)
select DocID
from tblDoc
where tblDoc.BatchID = #Batch_id#

select *
from tblPage
inner join [@docs]
on tblPage.DocID = [@docs].DocID
```

I've tried wrapping the @docs in square brackets, I've tried removing the where clause, I've tried different permutations of the insert command, all without success.

I keep getting either the

> must declare scalar variable @docs" message, or the "invalid object name message.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (RTM) - 10.0.1600.22

Comment: What version of SQL are you running on?

Comment: @RichBenner This looks like SQL Server, but maybe I'm wrong :-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'd agree, no idea what's happening in that where clause then

Comment: you are not showing complete code,your current code works and won't throw error messge

Comment: Added the rest of the code. The debugger is telling me that the error is on the line `where tblDoc.BatchID = #Batch_id#`, so I assumed that there would be no need to include anything after that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alias your table var

```
select *
from tblPage
inner join @docs d
on tblPage.DocID = d.DocID
```

just don't ask me why :)

Comment: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/329692/table-variable-inconsistent-brackets-required-or-not

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the brackets in JOIN. The following seems to work just fine:

```
create table tblDoc
(
    DocID int,
    BatchID INT
)

create table tblPage
(
    DocID int
)

declare @docs table(
    DocID int
)

insert into @docs (DocID)
select DocID
from tblDoc
where tblDoc.BatchID = 1

select *
from tblPage
inner join @docs
on tblPage.DocID = [@docs].DocID
```